# Integrating Juno IDE with Atom editor for julia in windows

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

After having installed Atom and then integrating it with Juno IDE from [here](https://github.com/JunoLab/uber-juno/blob/master/setup.md), i found this error shown at startup:-

```
Julia could not be found. We tried to launch Julia from: C:\Program Files\Julia-0.4.6\bin\julia.exe This path can be changed in the settings.
```

The installation path is correct. Then how to rectify this error?

**ADDENDUM**:
My `config.cson` file:

```
"*":
  autosave:
    enabled: true
  core:
    destroyEmptyPanes: false
    openEmptyEditorOnStart: false
    themes: [
      "atom-dark-ui"
      "atom-dark-syntax"
    ]
  editor:
    showIndentGuide: true
    tabLength: 4
  "exception-reporting":
    userId: "xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
  "julia-client":
    enableMenu: true
    enableToolBar: true
    juliaPath: "'C:\\Program Files\\Julia-0.4.6\\bin\\julia.exe'"
    launchOnStartup: true
  "tool-bar":
    position: "Left"
  "uber-juno":
    disable: true
  welcome:
    showOnStartup: false
```

Comment: Did you try and put the path in quotes?

Comment: @idleberg I tried double and single quotes--same problem.

Comment: And you're sure about that path? The default is `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Julia-0.4.6\bin`. To double-check that there aren't other issues, try installing to the default location using that path and see if it works.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas I tried default also and even that does not work. I changed path to Program files just for ease.

Comment: It may be easier to debug this in the [Juno Gitter](https://gitter.im/JunoLab/Juno).

Comment: Can you please add the exact path setting from your `config.cson` to your question?

Comment: @idleberg I added the file.

Comment: Try removing the single quotes from the path.

Comment: Has this been answered?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas No, couldn't figure out the IDE setup issue so have abandoned it for now. gone back to python and shall wait and see for out-of-box version of juno.

Comment: Was the error message the same after removing the single quotes? Have you gone to the Juno Gitter to debug this with the developers? Juno does do a straight install just by installing uber-juno on at least 3 different operating systems, so I'd like to help you but I need more information to re-create/debug what's going on but it's probably better in chat. If you copy-paste that path into your path into the CMD does it open Julia?

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Yes even after removing the single quotes, error remained. I tried double quotes, single quotes, no quotes! My work-space has been shifted since posting the question and i have been assigned a new pc. I shall again try Juno setup and if same error is encountered, then i shall post on juno gitter. Julia could be opened just by typing julia on command line on my previous workstation but i am not sure whether typing the whole path will also lead to same result. But thanks a lot for helping out and your concern.